# Why my nested route component is not working with react router dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to add Route to my `Shop` component and show `CollectionOverview` component but the `CollectionOverview` component is not showing and there are also no errors in console.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import CollectionsOverview from '../../Components/CollectionsOverview/CollectionsOverview';

const Shop = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <div className='shop-page'>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path={location.pathname}
          element={<CollectionsOverview />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

My code is working fine without `Route` but I want to add `Route`.

Answer (score 0):

When you nest routers, you don't need the full path name. You likely only need `/` such that your Route component looks like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<CollectionsOverview />" />
```

The reason this works is because you likely have something like this in an ancestor component (like your App component):

```
<Route exact path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
```

So when the user visits the URL `/shop`, your Shop component loads. Now, if you use a Route component in there, everything should be relative to `/shop`. This is why you can use `path="/"` inside the Shop component - react router already knows the user is at "/shop". To put it more simply, you could also do this:

```
<Route exact path="/shop" element={<Shop/>}>
   <Route exact path="/" element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
</Route>
```

Note: in the above example, you would need to use the `<Outlet />` component in your Shop component. I'm not covering all of that - I'm mostly just showing you how nested routes are relative to ancestor routes. I recommend following the guides on react router's documentation for all of the various ways of handling nested routing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of (potential) issues at play here. First is that you are rendering a ***descendent*** route, not a ***nested*** route. Descendent routes rendered in a `Routes` component will use ***relative*** paths from the parent route, so if you are wanting to render a descendent route on the same path as the parent then its path will simply be `"/"`.

Example:

```
const Shop = () => {
  return (
    <div className='shop-page'>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The second issue is that the parent route rendering `Shop` ***necessarily*** needs to specify a trailing wildcard `"*"` matcher to the path so that descendent routes *can* also be matched and rendered.

Example:

```
<Route path="/shop/*" element={<Shop />} />
```

The alternative is to actually render nested routes. The nested route rendering `CollectionsOverview` would be an index route to match and render when the parent route is matched.

Example:

```
const Shop = () => {
  return (
    <div className='shop-page'>
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element content here
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
<Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />}>
  <Route index element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
</Route>
```